# google+ api not using port number on redirect (Laravel Socialite)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, laravel-socialite

On my Google API page I have the following redirect URL set-up:

```
http://localhost:8002/callback/google
```

When I attempt the login I get a 400 error from Google:

```
Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

The redirect URI in the request, http://localhost/callback/google, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client.
```

Well, of course, it doesn't match because the port number 8002 seems to have been removed by Google. Yet when I go back to the control panel the redirect URL shows the port number still in the URL just fine.

Doe's anyone know whats happening here? How do I ensure the port number is kept during the redirect?

Comment: do you have port 8002 open to public traffic on your router/gateway?

Comment: It is not removed by Google, but by Socialite. You can solve it by changing the port to 80.

Comment: Make sure you have APP_URL set with the port specified in your .env file.